# Android tablet as 3G gateway - Limit tethering device 3G bandwidth

Tags: tethering, 3g, bandwidth, gateway

Scenario:
 
An Android tablet computer acts as 3G gateway for multiple devices connecting to it via WiFi; everything happens in a moving vehicle.

How can I limit the 3G/GPRS bandwidth of the devices connecting to the tablet, and secure a certain bandwidth for the tablet itself ? 

Also is there a limit in the number of connecting devices ?

Thanks!